# Comparing Python dictionaries at identical indices

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two large python dictionaries in the following form, and I want to compare them and report their mismatches at **identical indices**, for the **same key**. The dictionaries have the same keys, but the tuples do not have equal lengths.

```
d1 = {'a':(1,2,3,4,66,6,6,64), 'b':(3,2,5,3,2,1,1,1)}
d2 = {'a':(1,2,4,3,66,6,6,64), 'b':(1,8,5,3,2,1,22,9)}
```

For example, for key 'a', indices 2 and 3 different values.
As the dictionaries are large and the tuples lengths are not necessary equal, my amateur looping method doesn't work.

```
for k1,v1 in dict1:
    for k2, v2 in dict2:
        if k1 == k2:
           for i in range(len(v1)):
              for j in range(len(v2)):
                  if i==j:
                     if v1[i] != v2[j]:
                        print k1, v1[i]
                        print k2, v2[i]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The dictionary values are tuples with non-unique, un-ordered values.  Are you hoping to find the difference between items that have keys in both dictionaries?  How are you expect a comparison to work?  Should it return false unless the tuples are identical in value and order? Or if all values are present but in different order? How about all present but different number of occurences?

Comment: The two dictionaries have identical keys, but the values are tuples with unknown and unequal lengths. What I am hoping to get on my output is to print where the dictionaries have different values, for the same key and the same index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
for k in d1:
    if k not in d2:
        continue
    v1, v2 = d1[k], d2[k]
    for i in xrange(min(len(v1), len(v2))):
        if v1[i] != v2[i]:
            print k, i, v1[i]
            print k, i, v2[i]
```

That prints:

```
a 0 1
a 0 2
a 1 2
a 1 33
a 2 3
a 2 4
a 3 4
a 3 5
b 0 3
b 0 1
b 1 2
b 1 8
b 2 2
b 2 5
b 3 1
b 3 3
```

Nut sure if that's all you want.  What if the dicts don't have the same keys?  What about tuples with different lengths?  Etc.  Figure that all out, and you can adjust the above to do what you want ;-)

Comment: Yes, the output is exactly what I want. I just  need to solve the unequal lengths of tuples problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to handle all keys found in both dictionaries regardless of the order that they are returned by the dictionary iterator then do this:

```
d1k = set(d1.keys())
for d in d1k.intersection(d2.keys()):
    # handle tuple comparison
```

If you want to handle tuple comparison without considering ordering or duplication then something like:

```
if len d1[d] < d2[d]:
    for v in d1[d]:
        if v not in d2[d]:
            print d, v
else:
    for v in d2[d]:
        if v not in d1[d]:
            print d, v
```

Comment: in Python3, `keys()` already returns a set-like view object. With Python 2.7, use `viewkeys()`

Comment: Using viewkeys does not return an object with a method called intersection. I can instead change it to d1.viewkeys()&d2.viewkeys() .. without much benefit over what I have

Comment: Well it does save you the cost of creating a new set. Might be immaterial for small dictionaries, but the set's there for the taking and with large dictionaries, it should make a noticeable difference

Comment: It would be interesting to verify this.  Unless the internal storage of keys is a set then using set(d.keys()) or d.viewkeys() would seem to require getting the keys into a set (or set like) object external to the dictionary. I think I'll read Beautiful Code and see if that helps

Comment: Ok, after browsing PEP 3106, I see that viewkeys is expected to be more lightweight.  Thanks for the tip.